# Do i need to add objects dynamically in this case?

Tags: java

So i've been asked to create a simple solar system simulator for my coursework. Our lecturer has set out very specific guidelines in terms of the structure of constructors and methods of our classes.

I've been thinking about this for a couple of hours and don't understand how i can make this work without dynamic object allocation. I want to add planets onto the Planet[] array so they can be indexed, but i don't know how i should create the objects considering a requirement is that you can add planets to the system until the user types 'DONE'.

The Planet class is not one of the requirements but he recommended we use a class that can store the variables for a single planet and do calculations on it. Whereas the data should be stored in the main SolarSystem class. We also need to use a FantasySolarSystem class to read data from the user and deal with output.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SolarSystem{
    public static final int PLANET_MAX = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String systemName; 
        Planet[] planetArray = new Planet[PLANET_MAX]; //const for array size seemed easier than dynamically allocating memory
        SolarSystem mySystem = new SolarSystem("Boris");
        // below is testing the addplanet function
        addPlanet("Jimmy", 10, 100);
        System.out.print(Planet[0].planetName);
    }
    public SolarSystem(String name){
        systemName = name;
    }

    public static void addPlanet(String planetName, double planetMass, double planetDistance){
        Planet newPlanet = new Planet(planetName, planetMass, planetDistance);
        // all i want to do here is add planets on to the array
        Planet[0] = newPlanet;
    }
}
```

Just for reference here is the Planet class:

```
public class Planet{
    private String planetName;
    private double planetMass;
    private double planetDistance;
    private double planetPeriod;

    public Planet(String planetName, double planetMass, double planetDistance){
        this.planetName = planetName;
        this.planetMass = planetMass;
        this.planetDistance = planetDistance;
    }
    //sets the period for the current object
    public static calculatePeriod(double planetDistance){
        double period = Math.sqrt(planetDistance*planetDistance*planetDistance);
        setPlanetPeriod(period);
    }

    //accessors
    public String getPlanetName(){
        return planetName;
    }
    public double getPlanetMass(){
        return planetMass;
    }
    public double getPlanetDistance(){
        return planetDistance;
    }
    public double getPlanetPeriod(){
        return planetPeriod;
    }

    //mutators
    public void setPlanetName(String planetName){
        this.planetName = planetName;
    }
    public void setPlanetMass(double planetMass){
        this.planetMass = planetMass;
    }
    public void setPlanetDistance(double planetDistance){
        this.planetDistance = planetDistance;
    }
    public void setPlanetPeriod(double planetPeriod){
        this.planetPeriod = planetPeriod;
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

edit: I would just write it and test it but im getting errors saying, cannot find symbol in places referring to the object array

edit2: Fixed the accessing non-static methods from static methods issue, but still having problems with adding objects to arrays (still have 3 more cannot find symbol errors, with systemName=name; and both times i use Planet[0])

Comment: research static members in java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: hint: your method  `setPlanetPeriod(double planetPeriod)` is not `static`, so you can not call it from another static method `calculatePeriod()`